# "gpg-agent is older than us" warning message even after running gpgconf --kill all

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent, pgp

I have installed gpg version 2.2.17 from source.

When I run `gpg --card-status` gpg reports:

```
gpg: WARNING: server 'gpg-agent' is older than us (2.2.4 < 2.2.17).
gpg: Note: Outdated servers may lack important security fixes.
gpg: Note: Use the command "gpgconf --kill all" to restart them.
```

I have tried running the gpgconf command that was suggested but the problem persists.  I have also tried uninstalling gpg2 from the Ubuntu repositories using `sudo apt remove gpg2` and then rerunning `gpgconf --kill all` to no avail.

For good measure I even tried restarting my computer to kill the old version of `gpg-agent`.

Additionally, `gpg-agent --version` reports:

```
gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.2.17
libgcrypt 1.8.4
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: You may have multiple installations of `gpg-agent`? Does your system provide `gpg-agent` as a separate package that you have installed, or do you have older GnuPG versions installed? Where does `gpgconf` say the agent is living and is that the correct location?

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to Kusalananda for helping me find my problem.

The issue was that `gpg-agent` was still installed through `apt`. Running `sudo apt remove gpg-agent` followed by `gpgconf --kill all` fixed the issue.

Comment: In my case, only `gpgconf --kill all` solved the issue. My machine's uptime is 36 days and the GPG got updated during this time, which caused the warning.

Comment: @DiogoMelo, I keep forgetting and coming here to remember. Thanks!